# Can duplicated instances of a Symfony application use the same shared source code?

Tags: symfony

3 instances of the **same** Symfony application, located on the same server :

- URL > application local path > database used
- https://app1.myapp.com > /var/www/**app1** > app1 database
- https://app2.myapp.com > /var/www/**app2** > app2 database
- https://app3.myapp.com > /var/www/**app3** > app3 database

The 3 directories /var/www/appX/ are fully duplicated, but the app/config/parameters.yml file (database configuration) and the var directory (cache, logs, sessions, plus others files related to instance).

Purpose is to create many application instances using the same shared code source, to optimize installation, maintenance, php cache, disk space...
To get something like that :

- https://app1.myapp.com > /var/www/**app** > app1 database
- https://app2.myapp.com > /var/www/**app** > app2 database
- https://app3.myapp.com > /var/www/**app** > app3 database

A solution could be to share "only" the bin, src, tests, vendor and web directories, using symbolic links to unique shared directories ? With bad point : app directory remains duplicated.

But maybe there is a more official or solid way to do it ? I ask you for.

Using Symfony v3.4, MySQL v5.7, php 7.2, Debian OS.

Comment: Is dockerizing the apps an option? This would be a great usecase for that.

Comment: Not today, I'm not familiar with Docker. I understand how it could ease installs and upgrades, but not how to avoid directories duplication and get optimization coming from an unique shared PHP code source.

Comment: Your image would hold the "fixed" and shared code. Moving parts are mounted into the containers at runtime using volumes.

Comment: Make app load different parameters basing on domain, stuff in var/ can live together most probably

Comment: You can run the same application multiple times, but doing so requires some changes to the kernel. Basically you have to ensure that the configuration and the service container for each application are separated, e.g. by providing an app name to the kernel, which is used as a prefix or you could create different environments per application. Generally speaking the requirements/complications of having a shared code base are usually trickier to deal with then "wasting" disk space. That is why I avoid doing it, but it can work. It is just the initial effort for the setup that is deterring me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create different Environments. Instead of the known ones like dev or test, [create additional ones](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/environments.html) with app1, app2, app3. Then in your .htaccess file detect the host:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^app1\. APP=app1
SetEnvIf Host ^app2\. APP=app2
SetEnvIf Host ^app3\. APP=app3
```

and in the Rewrite section use your APP variable

```
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/%{ENV:APP}.php [L]
```

and you can load different Parameters for every Environment.